# C++ obfuscated typedef declaration

Tags: c++, typedef

What is the meaning of this declaration? (was given during an interview) :

```
typedef void * (A:: *B)(char *);
```

Comment: Pointer to a method on class A returning a pointer to void and taking a pointer to char.

Comment: All your answers are clear and concise, I think I was blinded by the pointer to member function  here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define `B` as a pointer to member-function of class `A`, which receives `char*` and returns `void*`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: C++11 uses `using B = void* (A::*)(char *);`. It is no so *old*.

Answer (score 5):

Declare `B` as the type of signature of member functions of class `A` getting a `char*` argument and returning a `void*` pointer.

I don't feel it is obfuscated. It permits much more readable code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807393/841108) (for C, but you could adapt it for C++).

Comment: Ok maybe it is not the correct word, let say it is not natural for some people to read it.

Comment: Well, avoiding such a `typedef` makes less readable code IMHO.

Comment: sure, I didnt meant the typedef was adding complexity to reading