# Storing an address into a function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvKC-4tCRgw) about calling the bootloader using software by assigning the address of the beginning of the system memory into a function pointer and then calling it, the expression for storing the address :

```
sysMemBootJump = (void(*)(void))(*(u32*)0x1fff0004);
```

"sysMemBootJump" is the function pointer.

But what I don't understand is, why did he dereference the address of the memory before casting it to void(*)(void) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the 'real' entry point is stored at that address. Think of it as being a pointer-to-pointer-to-function, by dereferencing you get just the pointer-to-function.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to:

```
u32 ad = *(u32*)0x1fff0004;
```

<sup>this is *fetching* a word located at address `0x1fff0004`</sup>

then

```
sysMemBootJump = (void(*)(void))ad;
```

So `0x1fff0004` is the address of a word containing the routine's address.

And notice that the code is *very* unportable. A more portable integral type castable to/from addresses is `uintptr_t`  from [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) ....

You can `typedef` function signatures, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807393/841108), to write more readable code.